# iOS Google Maps marker info window crashes when adding any subview(s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, infowindow

I'm using Google Maps Sdk installed over [Pods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleMaps). When I try to create a custom info window via the according delegate functions it only works when the view is empty (no subviews contained). This problem seems to be version dependent since my custom info window worked until a month ago. Did anybody came across the same issue.

I tried to look through iOS Google Maps issue tracker but I couldn't find anything.

Some code:

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{
     PPNearbyMarker *markerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PPNearbyMarker" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
     return markerView
 }
```

**Edit:**

There is no actual crash, it seems that the UI is blocked by a endless loop, deadlock or whatever. No exception is thrown. The metrics of the device are showing a high CPU usage and memory usage.

Comment: Can you please share error?

Comment: Have you tried to load this nib in a clean view controller to be sure this nib exists?

Comment: Yes nib is existing, I also tried to delete my existing nib file and it worked as long as i didn't add any subviews (UILabel, UIView).

Comment: @EktaMakadiya the strange thing is that I'm not getting any error. It seems to be a endless loop which blocks the UI

Comment: @PeterP Ok then I have another option that need to add that view on mapView and change the camera position according the view.